# How do I combine HDF5 arrays into a table?

Tags: python, arrays, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I have an HDF5 file containing 15 arrays and nothing else. Normally I would query this information using SQL, but the database is down and I have an HDF5 file and PyTables in its place. The only querying I can find on PyTables that outputs a "row" instead of specific elements from a column is done on Tables, not arrays.

Currently I've been creating the table from scratch in its own h5 file, populating each row individually, and flushing every once in a while. This takes a long time, since there are 29 million rows. Here is the code I've been using to create the table:

```
#Defining Table Structure
table_description = {
        'Column1':tables.FloatCol(),
        'Column2':tables.FloatCol(),
        'Column3':tables.FloatCol(),
         ....
        'Column15':tables.FloatCol()}

#Opening the HDF5 file
hdf5_file = h5py.File('File Path','r')

#Pulling out the arrays (the future columns)
Column1_array = np.array(hdf5_file.get('Column1'))
Column2_array = np.array(hdf5_file.get('Column2'))
Column3_array = np.array(hdf5_file.get('Column3'))
...
Column15_array = np.array(hdf5_file.get('Column15'))

#Creating a New H5 file
new_file = tables.open_file('new_table.h5','w')

#Creating a New Table in the File
tbl = new_file.create_table('/','Big_Table',table_description)

i = 0
row = tbl.row #A row pointer
while i < 29069765: #Since I know the length of the columns, I'm able to just index.
    row['Column1'] = Column1_array[i] #Filling each column in a row.
    row['Column2'] = Column2_array[i] #I have pulled each column out of the HDF5 file,
    row['Column3'] = Column3_array[i] #using h5py. 
    ...
    row['Column15'] = Column15_array[i]
    row.append() #Adding the row to the table
    i += 1
    if math.fmod(i,100) == 0: #Every 100 rows, I flush the table and the file
        tbl.flush()
        h5file.flush()

new_file.close()
```

I haven't even begun the process of querying it, but I plan to use the `Table.where()` function on `Big_Table`.

Is there a faster way to combine all these column arrays into a single table and run multi argument queries on it?

Comment: How about putting those `columns` array into a `pandas` dataframe, and write the table from there?  Each column should work as a `pandas` Series,  You might also be able to `column_stack` the arrays into one 2d array.  Filling the table one number at a time sure looks slow: `row['Column1'] = Column1_array[i] `  `Column1_array` is an array, and works best when treated as such.  Iterating like that is slower than with python lists!.

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying pandas! It has been quite slow, taking about an hour and a half to fill in the table. I will look into using pandas.

Comment: filling with a row iterator is the slowest possible method. Since you created an array for each column, just write each column's array to the matching field in `Big_Table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your example to read each 1-column table from the original file, then write the data to the new HDF5 file with a single table. This uses `get_node()` to access each table object along with the `.read()` method to read as a NumPy array. Data is written to the new table with the `.modify_column()`. Arguments are `column=` the data (eg Col_array), and `colname=` the column/field name to write the data (eg, Column#). Also I added a loop. This simplifies the code, and reduces the memory footprint because it only reads and writes one column of data at a time.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np
import h5py

##Code to create the first HDF5 file used in my example
#hdf5_file = h5py.File('SO_62782315_1.h5','w')
#
#for cnt in range(1,16,1):
#    arr = np.random.rand(1000)
#    hdf5_file.create_dataset('Column'+str(cnt),data=arr)
#hdf5_file.close()

#Defining Table Structure
table_dt = np.dtype( [ 
               ('Column1', 'f8'), ('Column2', 'f8'), ('Column3', 'f8'),
               ('Column4', 'f8'), ('Column5', 'f8'), ('Column6', 'f8'),
               ('Column7', 'f8'), ('Column8', 'f8'), ('Column9', 'f8'),
               ('Column10', 'f8'), ('Column11', 'f8'), ('Column12', 'f8'),
               ('Column13', 'f8'), ('Column14', 'f8'), ('Column15', 'f8') ] )   

#Creating a New H5 file
new_file = tb.open_file('SO_62782315_2.h5','w')

#Creating a New Table in the File
tbl = new_file.create_table('/','Big_Table',table_dt)
# create array of zeros and append to table to allocate space
table_arr = np.ndarray((1000,15),dtype=table_dt)
tbl.append(table_arr)   

#Open the existing HDF5 file with h5py
hdf5_file = h5py.File('SO_62782315_1.h5','r')

for cnt in range(1,16,1):
# alternate method (easier to program using a loop)
    Col_array = hdf5_file['Column'+str(cnt)][:]
    tbl.modify_column(column=Col_array, colname='Column'+str(cnt))
    h5file.flush()

new_file.close()
hdf5_file.close()
```

You can do everything with PyTables (`tables`) using this small modification to the open the file and read the array data.

```
#Open the existing HDF5 file with tables
hdf5_file = tb.File('SO_62782315_1.h5','r')

for cnt in range(1,16,1):
# alternate method (easier to program using a loop)
    Col_array = hdf5_file.get_node('/','Column'+str(cnt)).read()
    tbl.modify_column(column=Col_array, colname='Column'+str(cnt))
    new_file.flush()
```

Comment: This is so much simpler! I didn't even think about just modifying the already existing columns in the new table. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies in advance, I didn't test the code I posted. I just realized you are reading with `h5py` and writing with `tables`. That's not a problem, but my code won't work. Also, when you create a table with a dictionary for the description, there are NO rows, so you have to add blank rows to create space in the table. I updated the answer and it works with my dummy data.

Comment: One more thought: you probably won't have enough memory to create and append 29 million rows all in one shot. Likely you will have to tinker with creating `table_arr` and calling `.append()` -- start with 1 million rows, and repeat 29 times.

Comment: Thank you very much!